# Joining two tables without returning unwanted row

Tags: mysql, join

My table structure looks like this:

```
      tbl.users                       tbl.issues
+--------+-----------+   +---------+------------+-----------+
| userid | real_name |   | issueid | assignedid | creatorid |
+--------+-----------+   +---------+------------+-----------+
|   1    |   test_1  |   |    1    |     1      |     1     |
|   2    |   test_2  |   |    2    |     1      |     2     |
+--------+-----------+   +---------+------------+-----------+
```

Basically I want to write a query that will end in a results table looking like this:

```
                           (results table)
+---------+------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| issueid | assignedid | assigned_name | creatorid | creator_name |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
|    1    |     1      |    test_1     |    1      |    test_1    |
|    2    |     1      |    test_1     |    2      |    test_2    |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
```

My SQL looks like this at the moment:

```
SELECT 
  `issues`.`issueid`,
  `issues`.`creatorid`,
  `issues`.`assignedid`,
  `users`.`real_name`
FROM `issues`
JOIN `users` 
  ON ( `users`.`userid` = `issues`.`creatorid` )
  OR (`users`.`userid` = `issues`.`assignedid`)
ORDER BY `issueid` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This returns something like this:

```
                (results table)
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| issueid | assignedid | creatorid | real_name |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|    1    |     1      |     1     |   test_1  |
|    2    |     1      |     2     |   test_1  |
|    2    |     1      |     2     |   test_2  |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Can anyone help me get to the desired results table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  IssueID, 
  AssignedID, 
  CreatorID, 
  AssignedUser.real_name AS AssignedName, 
  CreatorUser.real_name AS CreatorName
FROM Issues
  LEFT JOIN Users AS AssignedUser
         ON Issues.AssignedID = AssignedUser.UserID
  LEFT JOIN Users AS CreatorUser
         ON Issues.CreatorID = CreatorUser.UserID
ORDER BY `issueid` ASC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: I guess that there are two foreign keys from issues.creatorid, issues.assignedid to users.userid, and that nothing can be null in each table. Given these premises, is there any difference between using left joins and inner joins? Is one more natural, or faster, than the other?

Answer (score 3):

On the general knowledge front, our illustrious site founder wrote a very nice blog article on this subject which I find myself referring to over and over again.

### [Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT 
`issues`.`issueid`,
`issues`.`creatorid`,
`creator`.`real_name`,
`issues`.`assignedid`,
`assigned`.`real_name`
FROM `issues` i
INNER JOIN `users` creator ON ( `creator`.`userid` = `issues`.`creatorid` )
INNER JOIN `users` assigned ON (`assigned`.`userid` = `issues`.`assignedid`)
ORDER BY `issueid` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (i.issueid, i.creatorid, i.assignedid, u.real_name)
FROM issues i, users u
WHERE u.userid = i.creatorid OR u.userid = assignedid
ORDER BY i.issueid ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Not sure if the parenthesis are needed or not.

Comment: Sorry, this still returns a double row for issue #2.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

SELECT
i.issueid,
i.assignedid,
u1.real_name as assigned_name,
i.creatorid,
u2.real_name as creator_name
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN issues i ON u1.userid = i.assignedid
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.userid = i.creatorid
ORDER BY i.issueid

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
i.issueid,
i.assignedid,
a.real_name,
i.creatorid,
c.real_name
FROM
issues i
INNER JOIN users c
ON c.userid = i.creatorid
INNER JOIN users a
ON a.userid = i.assignedid
ORDER BY
i.issueid ASC